# D3.js: Image is not clipped to projection during rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

I am re-projecting an image onto a canvas element using d3's d3.geo. I want to allow most projections (Eckert, Polyconic, Orthographic, Albers, etc). I am allowing the user to zoom and pan with the mousewheel/curosor.

Initially, image renders correctly onto the canvas. The zoom control seems to work correctly as well. However, when I rotate the canvas element the image seems to escape the clipping bounds of the projection. This causes a weird duplication effect that I find difficult to describe in words.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9Br/) of this situation.

**Edit: Picture examples**:

```
Zoomed-out:
```

[image: Zoomed-out]

```
Zoomed-out-and-nudged (translated):
```

[image: Zoomed-out-and-nudged]

**Edit #2: Clearer example**
I made a fiddle with a different projection and with some unrelated code removed: http://jsfiddle.net/bB6hD/

```
Zoomed-out:
```

[image: Zoomed-out]

```
Zoomed-out-and-nudged:
```

[image: Zoomed-out-and-nudged]

I removed the scaling and translating aspects entirely, so this seems to be cause (at least indirectly) by rotation.

I was trying to follow this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4329423, but with the addition of rotation and zooming.

The following is the same code as the fiddle:

```
var scale = 1,
    radius = 150;
var width = 300,
    height = 300;

var projection = d3.geo.kavrayskiy7();

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.onload = onload;
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
image.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/j8v1nvyz6gmo8u7/tooth-color-300x300.jpg";

function onload() {
    var dx = image.width,
        dy = image.height;

    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, dx, dy);

    var sourceData = context.getImageData(0, 0, dx, dy).data,
        target = context.createImageData(width, height),
        targetData = target.data;

    for (var y = 0, i = -1; y < height; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            var p = projection.invert([x, y]),
                λ = p[0],
                φ = p[1];
            if (λ > 180 || λ < -180 || φ > 90 || φ < -90) {
                i += 4;
                continue;
            }
            var q = ((90 - φ) / 180 * dy | 0) * dx + ((180 + λ) / 360 * dx | 0) << 2;
            targetData[++i] = sourceData[q];
            targetData[++i] = sourceData[++q];
            targetData[++i] = sourceData[++q];
            targetData[++i] = 255;
        }
    }

    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.putImageData(target, 0, 0);
}

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()

    .center([width / 2, height / 2])
    .on("zoomstart", function () {
    console.log('zoom');
    m0 = [d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX, d3.event.sourceEvent.pageY];
    var proj = projection.rotate();
    o0 = [-proj[0], -proj[1]];
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
})
    .on("zoom", function () {
    if (m0) {
        var constant = (scale < 4) ? 4 : scale * 2;
        var m1 = [d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX, d3.event.sourceEvent.pageY],
            o1 = [o0[0] + (m0[0] - m1[0]) / constant, o0[1] + (m1[1] - m0[1]) / constant];
    }
    rotate = [-o1[0], -o1[1]];
    scale = (d3.event.scale >= .25) ? d3.event.scale : .25;
    projection.scale((radius - 2) * scale).rotate(rotate).translate([width / 2, height / 2]).precision(2);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    onload();
});

d3.select('canvas').call(zoom);
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about how the map projections work, but I would just like to say that that is the trippiest fiddle example I've seen yet!

Comment: lol yeah, i had no intention of making it so entertaining... some things just happen i guess

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say that it escapes the clipping bounds -- the projection "wraps around" when you translate it beyond a certain point (also observable when you zoom out). Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Yes, that is what I am talking about. However I do not observe this effect when I zoom out without translating. I will update my initial post with the before/after

Comment: If I understand correctly, then this is pretty much by design -- depending on the projection, they will wrap around (see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3763057)).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I made a clearer example: http://jsfiddle.net/bB6hD/
Do you think this is by design? From my understanding the image should have stayed within its initial bounds (in that oval).

Comment: Well when you rotate the projection, the initial oval wouldn't be an oval anymore. I'm not sure about the wrapping though -- the D3 mailing list may be a better place to ask about this.